# gradle-swagger-generator-plugin not working with java 17

Tags: java, gradle, gradle-plugin, swagger-codegen

I tried to update in gradle project java version from 11 to 17.

After update gradle-swagger-generator-plugin started to producing following error:

```
    com.github.jknack.handlebars.HandlebarsException: /handlebars/JavaSpring/pojo.mustache:2:6: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make public boolean java.util.Collections$EmptyMap.isEmpty() accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.util" to unnamed module @2f465398

Caused by: com.github.jknack.handlebars.HandlebarsException: /handlebars/JavaSpring/pojo.mustache:2:6: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make public boolean java.util.Collections$EmptyMap.isEmpty() accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.util" to unnamed module @2f465398

    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:354)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:297)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.checkCanSetAccessible(Method.java:199)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.setAccessible(Method.java:193)
    at com.github.jknack.handlebars.context.MemberValueResolver.cache(MemberValueResolver.java:82)
    at com.github.jknack.handlebars.context.MemberValueResolver.resolve(MemberValueResolver.java:54)
    ...
    at com.github.jknack.handlebars.internal.ForwardingTemplate.apply(ForwardingTemplate.java:72)
    at io.swagger.codegen.v3.templates.HandlebarTemplateEngine.getRendered(HandlebarTemplateEngine.java:25)
    at io.swagger.codegen.v3.DefaultGenerator.processTemplateToFile(DefaultGenerator.java:735)
    at io.swagger.codegen.v3.DefaultGenerator.generateModels(DefaultGenerator.java:392)
```

My build.gradle:

```
buildscript {

    dependencies {
        classpath('gradle.plugin.org.hidetake:gradle-swagger-generator-plugin:2.19.2')
    }
}
plugins {
    ...
    id 'org.hidetake.swagger.generator' version '2.19.2'
}
```

I tried solution:
https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/issues/10966

```
buildscript {

    dependencies {
        classpath('gradle.plugin.org.hidetake:gradle-swagger-generator-plugin:2.19.2')
        classpath("com.github.jknack:handlebars:4.3.1") {
            force: true
        }
    }
}
```

and also I tried to add

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=--add-opens java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED
```

in gradle.proprties

Sadly nothing changed.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the old Version of **swagger-codegen-cli**
After I replaced

```
dependencies {
  ...
  swaggerCodegen("io.swagger.codegen.v3:swagger-codegen-cli:3.0.5")
  ...
}
```

with

```
dependencies {
  ...
  swaggerCodegen("io.swagger.codegen.v3:swagger-codegen-cli:3.0.41")
  ...
}
```

swagger generation works